# Get the current Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a DialogFragment I have a Listener where I use a callback like:

```
OnDoneListener caller = (OnDoneListener)getActivity(); 
caller.done();
```

However, instead of implementing OnDoneListener in a FragmentActivity I would like to implement it in Fragment. Therefore I'm looking for something like:

```
OnDoneListener caller = (OnDoneListener)getFragmentManager().getFragment(); //made up
```

I found findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag() but I would like it more generic... or how can I get Id or Tag? Can I get it from container or parent?

**EDIT:**
Just to make that clear. My DialogFragment should be as reusable as possible. Therefore I don't want any hardcoded IDs and TAGs. I just want to refer to my parent (calling) Fragment which needs to implement OnDoneListener.

Comment: AFAIK DialogFragment uses own Activity, so result cannot be passed to different Activity using listener, it need to be more generic solution like startActivityForResult()

Comment: I can be passed to a different FragmentActivity. That's what I've done so far. Now I'd like to pass it to a Fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

CallerFragment:

```
mCalledFragment = new CalledFragment();
mCalledFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
```

CalledFragment:

```
CallerFragment caller = (CallerFragment)getTargetFragment();
caller.callback();
```